# Excel Document Crashes In Microsoft Teams while Co-authoring Office 365

Tags: office-365, excel, microsoft-teams

While editing Excel document in MS Teams, The excel document we are collaborating on crashes and all the work is lost. I have attached screenshots.

Any suggestion please? Is this a known issue?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps these links could help, since they report similar issues:

Microsoft [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/links-disabled-error-in-excel-online/05be284c-6e79-4c9b-9ff8-79b6d52fc691)
Microsoft 'uservoice' [link](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/32809945-linked-workbooks-in-excel)

I am using SP 2013, so I'm afraid I can't do any testing myself.

In the second link, one user replied (sic):

"I agree with all you. I eventually gave up, and started using the Sharepoint Lists and setup the Sharepoint Lists Data connector in Excel (Only available if you have an O365 E3 License (Not available in O365 Business Premium). But in my Scenario, I only needed to pull over our master data sheet (Vendors names, Employee ID's etc.). And have our people update the list in Sharepoint. This fixed my problem. But May not fix your's"